# Problem in understanding an equation from a paper about iterative Linear-Quadratic Regulator

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming

I'm reading a paper about iterative Linear-Quadratic Regulator (iLQR) and there are a lot of points that I don't understand.

[https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/papers/TassaICRA14.pdf](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Etodorov/papers/TassaICRA14.pdf)

[image]

I think equation (5b) is deduced by

[image]

But after getting equation (5b), I still have zero idea how equations (6a), (6b), and (6c) are deduced.

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760601/how-are-equation-6-deduced